# Prototype new Element name

Tags: prototypejs, element

Everytime I define a new Element with Prototype such as:

```
var iframe = new Element('iframe', {
    name: 'preview_frame',
    id: 'preview_frame',
    src: 'form/' + formID + '?prev',
    allowtransparency: true,
    frameborder: 0
})
```

when I include the 'name' field in the list of attributes I get a  DOM Exception 5

However when I do this:

```
var iframe = new Element('iframe', {
    id: 'preview_frame',
    src: 'form/' + formID + '?prev',
    allowtransparency: true,
    frameborder: 0
})
iframe.name = 'preview_frame';
```

Then I don't get the error.

Comment: It seems to work for me (Chrome 18): http://jsfiddle.net/keLgs/

Answer (score 2):

In your browser, "name" may be a reserved word in JavaScript (or stepping on another property).

In order to specify an object property for a reserved word in an object-literal declaration, put it in quotes, like this:

```
var iframe = new Element('iframe', {
   "name": 'preview_frame',
   "id": 'preview_frame',
   "src": 'form/' + formID + '?prev',
   "allowtransparency": true,
   "frameborder": 0
})
```

Note that while you don't have to put ALL your properties in quotes, you can.
See the Mozilla doc on reserved words on how to get around it: [Mozilla JS Reserved Words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)